# How insert values in multi Choice filed of sharepoint Survey list using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am trying to add survey using REST API.I have one Column As Multichoice.

When I am trying to add multichoice field value but its give Bad Request Error.

I am trying like below:

```
"InternalFieldName":{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":["Value1","Value2","Value3"]}
```

But it's not Work.

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your code? JSON seems correct. So problem will be in your code.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution if i will not pass this value in json then its works so there is not problem in code. I think in survey list you cant add multivalue.